# CI/CD Flutter web to Firebase Hosting

Tags: flutter, cicd

I have implemented CI/CD to deploy FLutter web to Firebase Hosting. After successfully implementing CI/CD, my website still cannot be launched and shows an error like the following image
[image]

**Here is my CI/CD command:**

```
name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on PR STG
'on':
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - staging
      - develop
jobs:
  build_and_preview:
    if: '${{ github.event.pull_request.head.repo.full_name == github.repository }}'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Install Flutter
        run: git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b 3.13.6 --depth 1
      - name: Add path
        run: echo "$(pwd)/flutter/bin" >> $GITHUB_PATH
      - name: Download Flutter packages
        run: flutter pub get
      - name: Set Web icons for stg
        run: FLAVOR=stg ./deploy.sh
      - name: Build Flutter Web
        run: flutter build web  --web-renderer html --dart-define=FLAVOR=stg --dart-define=WEB_RENDERER=html
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
          firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_<project> }}'
          channelId: live
          projectId: <project>
          target: <target>
          firebaseToolsVersion: 11.24.1
```

**Github Action run:**
[image: Github Action run]